# jQuery cannot capture href in Bonitasoft

Tags: jquery

I have some issue regarding jQuery in Bonitasoft. I called href in jQuery code but it is undefined when it run on browser. But, if I called the href in console, it displayed the download link.

Here is the code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var attachLeave = function()
    {
        console.log('kucingku comel')
        var leave1 =  $('#leaveType1').find('select').val();
        var btn = $('#Submit1').find('button');
        console.log (leave1);
        if(leave1 == "Medical Leave"){
             btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             btn.attr('style', 'color:black');
        }
        else{
             btn.removeAttr('disabled');
             btn.attr('style', 'color:white');
        }
    }

var attachmentUpload = function()   
{
    console.log('enter attachment validation');
    var UploadEx = $('#File1').find('.bonita_file_upload').val();
    var uploadFile = $('#File1').find('.bonita_download_link');
    var btn = $('#Submit1').find('button');
    uploadFile.attr('href');
    console.log('download-link ' + uploadFile.attr('href'));
    if(uploadFile.attr('href') != "null")
    {
        console.log('Ready to download');
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        btn.attr('style', 'color:white');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Download is blank");
        btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        btn.attr('style', 'color:black');
    }

} 

    console.log('ayam goreng');
    //$('#Submit1').find('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var leave1 =  $('#leaveType1').find('select');
    leave1.change(attachLeave);
    //attach file or URL to attachment
    var uploadExcuse =  $('#File1').find('.bonita_file_upload');
    uploadExcuse.on('change', attachmentUpload);
});
</script>
```

Note that I have called the href in the jQuery code, but it is still undefined.

I hope anyone here can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it something like this:

```
attachmentUpload = function(e)   {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Holds all the file related data
    var Files = e.target.files[0];

    console.log( Files );

    // Do what you want
}
```

### Description:

`e.target.files` return array of files data like file type, file name etc. By default form upload only allow single file upload, It means `e.target.files` has only single file,
But if you add multiple attribute in file type element then on change event `e.target.files` returns all the selected files data in array like

```
// Depends on your selected files 
// And better way is use for loop for multi file upload
e.target.files[0], 
e.target.files[1], 
.............
```

Comment: What does [0] means? Can you explain more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ooh...thanks, it works. My current issue is I want to validate whether the file is uploaded or not. If the file is upload or removed, how to validate the file is upload/removed? I have tried if else, but it does not work. Can you help me? Thanks